# Find the number of integer solutions for $x_1+x_2+x_3\le15$

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

For equation
$x_1+x_2+x_3\le15$

Find the number of positive (including 0) integer solutions on conditions:

$x_1\ge4$

$x_3 \in \{2,5,7\}$

I have tried using inclusion-exclusion

Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly. Use inclusion-exclusion. Where is the question?

Comment: I have tried but didn't succeed.

Comment: @Jhon Where did you get stuck when trying inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: To simplify stuff, rewrite the equation as $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=15$ with $9\geq x_4\geq 0$. The nine was obtained by trying to get the minimum value of the sum which is six.

Comment: You neither need nor want to use the principle of inclusion and exclusion.  Solve for $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 11$.  The solutions to this are in $1$-$1$ correspondence with the solutions to your system with $x_3$ unconstrained.  Now just count how many different solutions for each value of $x_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You neither need nor want to use the principle of inclusion and exclusion.  Solve for $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 11$.  The solutions to this are in $1$-$1$ correspondence with the solutions to your system with $x_3$ unconstrained.  Now just count how many different solutions for each value of $x_3$.

For $x_3=2$:  How many solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_4=9$?  $\binom{11}{2}=55$

For $x_3=5$:  How many solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_4=6$?  $\binom{8}{2}=28$

For $x_3=7$:  How many solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_4=4$?  $\binom{6}{2}=15$

Use stars and bars to answer these three questions as above, then add the answers to see that there are $98$ possible solutions.